# Railo: Form field [asset[file]] doesn't exist or has no content

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels, cffile

I am trying to add file uploading to my CFWheels + Railo application. But I keep getting this error message when trying to use `<cffile action="upload">`:

```
Form field [asset[file]] doesn't exist or has no content
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple hours of beating my head against the wall, I realized that I didn't set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form tag.

Fortunately, this is a fairly simple fix using the CFWheels [`startFormTag()`](http://cfwheels.org/docs/function/startformtag) form helper and its `multipart` argument:

```
#startFormTag(route="assets", multipart=true)#
  ...
#endFormTag()#
```